# Bar chart blurs on production environment but on staging it's sharp & correct

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-redux, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I have used bar chart from chart.js 2 library in react.
On localhost & staging the chart is getting displayed properly. But on running the same code on production bar chart becomes blur.

```
           <div className="ibox-content" 
                 style={{"borderRadius":"0",
                         "borderWidth": "2px 1px" }}>
              <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-lg-12">
                    <Bar width={100} height={250} 
                        data ={this.props.barData}
                        options = {this.props.barOptions}
                    />   
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

[image: Production view of chart][image: Staging & local view of chart]

Comment: it seems either there is some code in production page not present on dev and staging, and/or new css and assets are not being used, and may need cache busting

Comment: yes it was a caching issue. It's working now. Thanks!